# Why this command works on shell, but not on vim?

Tags: awk, vim

I want to insert a blank line every two lines.
This command is perfect on shell
I can use it "directly"

```
awk 'ORS=NR%1?RS:RS RS'
```

or with a pipe

```
printf "%s\n" {a..z} | awk 'ORS=NR%1?RS:RS RS'
```

but on vim(where i need it!), I select with "visual" lshift+v my 56 lines, I put this

```
:'<,'>!awk 'ORS=NR%2?RS:RS RS'
```

and instead of inserting the blank line return me this error

```
awk: row com.:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: attempt to divide by zero
```

Why? I'm on Slackware, with Gawk

Comment: `:'<,'>g#$#norm o` would also do it.

Comment: To avoid surprises don't use the result of an action as a condition unless you **need** to do so. You should use `awk '{ORS=NR%2?RS:RS RS}1'` (or better `awk '{ORS=RS(NR%2?"":RS)}1'` to reduce duplicate code), not `awk 'ORS=NR%2?RS:RS RS'`. I've no idea if that's your problem, though, since I'd never dream of doing something like this in vim!

Comment: The `%` character is special in Vim, expands to the name of the current buffer. You need to escape it: `:'<,'>!awk 'ORS=NR\%2?RS:RS RS'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution/workaround using sed, this insert one empty line every two lines

```
:'<,'>!sed '0~2 s/$/\n/g'
```